# Task from Automate Boring Stuff With Python chap. 5

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a new at learning python with book *Automate Boring Stuff With Python* by Albert Sweigart.

```
inventory = {'arrows': 12, 'gold coins': 42, 'rope': 1, 'torches': 6, 'dagger': 1}
```

From this dictionary I need to make output like this:

```
Inventory:
12 arrows
42 gold coins
1 rope
6 torches
1 dagger
Total number of items: 62
```

So far I make something like this and I try to use methods from the book:

```
inventory = {'arrows': 12, 'gold coins': 42, 'rope': 1, 'torches': 6, 'dagger': 1}

def displayInventory(inventory):
    totalNum = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(v, k)
        totalNum = totalNum + sum(inventory.values())
    print("Total items of inventory: ")
    return totalNum

print("Your inventory: ")
print(displayInventory(inventory))
```

Output:

```
Your inventory:
12 arrows
42 gold coins
1 rope
6 torches
1 dagger
Total items of inventory:
310
```

Why my `totalNum` is so big?

Comment: You must either calculate the `sum` of all items after the for-loop or only add the value of the current item in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 5 elements in the dictionary. Your values are (12 + 42 + 1 + 6 + 1) = 62. 62*5 = 310.

You are taking the sum of all inventory.values() each time you go through an item. If you are doing it within the loop, then it should be

```
totalNum = totalNum + v
```

If you want to do it outside the loop, then it should be

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(v, k)
    print("Total items of inventory: ")
    return sum(inventory.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `totalNum` different than expected because in each iteration your are incrementing the value of `totalNum` by `62` because `sum(inventory.values())` will return `62`. So after five iterations `totalNum` will be `310`.

Just in case you want more compact version of your code, Use:

```
print("Inventory:")
print("\n".join(f"{v} {k}"for k, v in inventory.items()))
print("Total number of items:", sum(inventory.values()))
```

This prints:

```
Inventory:
12 arrows
42 gold coins
1 rope
6 torches
1 dagger
Total number of items: 62
```